# scanf inside while loop keeps modifieing array's previous values

Tags: c, while-loop, scanf

I'm trying to implement a hash table in C so the idea is simple:

1- the user enters a string
2- the program adds it to the table
3- prints the whole table

but I noticed that the program replaces all previous values with the new one !!
THE CODE:

```c
//edit
//initialize array to empty string
void init(char* table[]){
    for (int i=0; i<T_LEN; i++){
        table[i] = "";
    }
}

int hash(char* str){
    int result = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<sizeof(str); i++){
        result += str[i]; 
    }
    return result % T_LEN;
}

void add(char* table[]){
    char* input;
    printf("> ");
    scanf("%s", (char*)&input);
    int index = hash((char*)&input);
    table[index] = (char*)&input;
    return;
}

int main(){
    char* hash_table[T_LEN];
    init(hash_table);
    while(1){
        add(hash_table);
        print_table(hash_table);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

RESULT:

```bash
> abc
1         -------
2         -------
3         -------
4         -------
5         abc
6         -------
7         -------
8         -------
9         -------
10        -------
> esd
1         -------
2         -------
3         -------
4         -------
5         esd
6         -------
7         esd
8         -------
9         -------
10        -------
> ee
1         -------
2         -------
3         ee
4         -------
5         ee
6         -------
7         ee
8         -------
9         -------
10        -------
```

EDIT:
the site says "It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details." so here I'm :D

Comment: Variable `input`  is uninitialized.  That's bad!  The cast not tells the compiler you know what you're doing; unfortunately, the code shows that you don't.

Comment: Your `char *input` is not initialized. How do you compile it not seeing warnings? Also, why do you cast `char *` to the same type?

Comment: @dimich `&input` is a `char **` that is cast to a `char *`.

Comment: It's a good idea to separate i/o from calculations (i.e. do scanf in main() and pass the result to add).

Comment: Ah, it is casting `char **` to `char *`. Much more wierd. Also no result checking for `scanf`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler initialize it to what ? empty string? I'm pretty new to C so it's not clear to me why! and I saw lot of other programmers code and they're not init theyr variables espicially INTs

Comment: @AllanWind I tried it but didn't help ..

Comment: Can you update your code to be a [mre].  Even if stump over random memory, I would like to know how you initialize your hash_table array of pointers.  Moving `scanf()` out of add just leads to a better design and is not expected to fix anything.  It may prompt you to allocate the string you pass to scanf.

Comment: @AllanWind I initialized it with for-loop to set each element to empty string (""), take a look at the update

Comment: You never allocate space for any of the strings in the hash table, or the string that you read with `scanf`.  Also, the cast `(char *)&input` is an immediate red flag, since you're deliberately trying to bypass C's type system.  And in this case, as expected, it's a bug.  You don't have a character array in which to store the string.  Instead, you have a pointer, which you are trying to treat as a character array, storing the characters directly in the pointer variable.  Bad, bad, bad.  Even when that works, `input` is a local variable and it goes out of scope when the function returns.

Comment: If you want persistent memory for the strings in your hash table, you need to use `malloc`.

Comment: @TomKarzes that's really good explaination, any solution I could do?

Comment: @TomKarzes ohh, so now the hash_table array strings are pointing to the same memory that's why when modifying it all the previous changes?

Comment: @at_Root Yes, and even worse, that memory resides on the stack where is will be overwritten by subsequent function calls.

Comment: @at_Root There are actually a lot of bugs in this code.  Another one is the use of `sizeof` to determine string length.     When applied to an array, it gives the size of the array, but in your case you're applying it to a pointer, which is going to be a constant size.  You need to call `strlen` to obtain the string length (but don't do it in the loop test - do it once, before you enter the loop, to avoid repeated calls).

Comment: Also, just adding the character values is a very poor hash function.  Consider:  The following strings will all have the same hash value:  `abc`, `acb`, `bac`, `bca`, etc. etc.  In cases like that, which are not uncommon, you'll end up with all of those values landing in the same hash bucket.

Comment: And I don't see any logic to handle hash collisions, so your hash table will overwrite values that have the same hash value.

Comment: @TomKarzes yes I know about the collision it's just for practical reasons ,and thank you very much , I started to see the road now good bless you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

some problems with your code:

1. `return;` at the end of the function called `add` is redundant which means that it has no meaning as in all the cases the function will end at this point

---

2. the compiler is giving the warning `while(1)` in the `main` as you don't return from the function, so you can do

   ```
   int __attribute__((noreturn)) main()
   ```

to tell the compiler that the `main` will never return

---

3. in the function called `init`, as you are declaring an array of pointers, then it's better to write:

   ```
   table[i] = malloc(sizeof(char) * MAX_NAME_LEN);
   table[i][0] = '\0';
   ```

instead of:

```
 table[i] = "";
```

to reserve memory in **heap** for the string not in the **read-only** memory.

---

4. in the lines:

   ```
   scanf("%s", (char*)&input);
   int index = hash((char*)&input);
   ```

the pointer called `input` is already of type `char*`, so you don't have to cast it as it's not a better practice to cast everything, also you should reserve a space for the `input` variable in the heap memory like:

```
   char* input = malloc(sizeof(char) * MAX_NAME_LEN);
```

and so your code becomes:

```
    char* input = malloc(sizeof(char) * MAX_NAME_LEN);
    printf("> ");
    scanf("%s", input);
    int index = hash(input);
    table[index] = input;
```

---

5. instead of `sizeof()` in the line:

   ```
    for (int i=0; i<sizeof(str); i++)
   ```

I think you should use `strlen` instead like:

```
for (int i=0; i<strlen(str); i++)
```

as `sizeof(str) = 4` as `sizeof(pointer) = 4` as the pointers has fixed size

---

with all this being said, this is the edited code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define T_LEN 10
#define MAX_NAME_LEN    20

void print_table(char* table[])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < T_LEN; ++i) {
        printf("%d\t\t%s\n",i, table[i]);
    }
}

//edit
//initialize array to empty string
void init(char* table[]){
    for (int i=0; i<T_LEN; i++){
        table[i] = malloc(sizeof(char) * MAX_NAME_LEN);
        table[i][0] = '\0';
    }
}

int hash(char* str){
    int result = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<strlen(str); i++){
        result += str[i];
    }
    return result % T_LEN;
}

void add(char* table[]){
    char* input = malloc(sizeof(char) * MAX_NAME_LEN);
    printf("> ");
    scanf("%s", input);
    int index = hash(input);
    table[index] = input;
}

int __attribute__((noreturn)) main(){
    char* hash_table[T_LEN];
    init(hash_table);
    while(1){
        add(hash_table);
        print_table(hash_table);
    }
}
```

and this is some output:

```
>abc
0
1
2
3
4               abc
5
6
7
8
9
>esd
0
1
2
3
4               abc
5
6               esd
7
8
9
>ee
0
1
2               ee
3
4               abc
5
6               esd
7
8
9
>
```